# Best way to init an array of views in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uikit

I'm writing a new subclass of UIView using swift. I want to have an array of views, and I want to instantiate them in the initial declaration, for clarity.

If this was an Int array, I could do something like this:

```
let values: [Int] = (0...4).map() { $0 }
```

and so I'm trying to come up with some sort of similarly swifty one-liner that will create an array of UIButtons, instead of Ints.

my first thought was `(0...4).map() { UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) }` but if I do this (or if I replace the UIButton code with, say NSObject()) I get an error saying that "'Transition' does not have a member named 'map'". I *can*, say, do `map() { "\($0)" }` and get an array of strings.

My next thought was just to get an array of ints first, and then use map on *those* to return buttons, like:

```
let values: [UIButton] = (0...4)
    .map() { $0 }
    .map() { UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) }
```

but this gives me the same error. What am I doing wrong, here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, the solution came to me pretty quickly: I guess I can't quietly ignore the variable of the closure I'm passing in to the map function; I need to ignore it explicitly. So to get my array of 4 buttons, I can use an _ in the map function, like this:

```
var buttons = (0...4).map() {_ in UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) }
```

or what I actually ended up using:

```
lazy var buttons: [UIButton] = (0...4).map() { _ in
    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
    self.addSubview(button)
    return button
}
```

Comment: Do you feel that this is the most **clear** way you could code this? Or perhaps the most "cute" way. Clarity to future readers is the big win. Brian Kernighan: "If you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Comment: well I intentionally left in the (optional) [UIButton] type annotation, to make it clear that this produces an array of UIButtons. We're obviously still figuring out what best practices are going to be for writing Swift, but I think once you've seen this once it shouldn't feel too crazy afterwards?